# PHP session_start() function: Why I need it everytime I use anything related to PHP sessions

Tags: php, session, logout

For logging out a user from my website, I am redirecting the page to `logout.php` where I am using session_destroy() function. Even there also, logout functionality is not working without `session_start()` function. By adding session_start() function before `session_destroy()` function, I am able to logout the user successfully.

Why do I need to use `session_start()` function everytime and in every page where I am doing something related to sessions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869959/when-and-where-should-i-use-session-start

Answer (score 15, accepted):

session_destroy() destroys the active session. If you do not initialized the session, there will be nothing to be destroyed.

Comment: So, do I need to initialize session on each and every page where the page can be seen by only logged-in users? I thought by calling session_start() every page comes to know that there is a session variable set.

Comment: Absolutely. If you are ever dealing with sessions in the request, you are required to call session_start() to give PHP the session information.

Comment: OR you could use session.auto_start = 1 (it's not best practice, but it's possible =)

Answer (score 13):

> Why do I need to use session_start() function everytime and in every page where I am doing something related to sessions?

So PHP knows which session to destroy. `session_start()` looks whether a session cookie or ID is present. Only with that information can you destroy it.

Comment: Thanks Pekka for the answer. Can I create more than one sessions? For example, I call session_start() function 4 times. It creates 4 sessions?

Comment: Likely you are only creating a single session. After you call your first session_start(), unless you specify a different session id to the subsequent session_start() calls, it is defaulting to the original session id (stored in the users cookie or url).

Comment: @iSumitG What @John says.  I think starting a session more than once even throws an error - and it wouldn't make sense in the first place

Comment: @Pekka, you can only run one session at a time, correct. However, you can start, maintain, and save to multiple sessions on a single site for a user by forcing a session ID before `session_start`. Examples of this might be site/forum sessions vs. cart sessions.

Comment: If you wanted to get rediculous you could even juggle (in theory) :P

Answer (score 5):

In the default configuration, PHP Sessions operate off of the hard disk. PHP asks you to explicitly tell it when you need this support to avoid unnecessary disk IO.

`session_start()` also tells PHP to find out if the user's session exists.

Answer (score 4):

> session_start() creates a session or
>   resumes the current one based on a
>   session identifier passed via a GET or
>   POST request, or passed via a cookie.

as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Essentially by calling `session_start()`, PHP reads the header and cross references that session ID to what is on your system(file system/database/etc), which can then populate the `$_SESSION` that is relavent to that specific user. Which in turn allows you to call `session_destroy()` because it knows what session to actually destroy.

Answer (score 1):

consider session_start() as your way of telling the php engine.... that you want to work with sessions.

and, as i understand it, always make that to be the first line ever in php page.

Answer (score 1):

I was confused with the usage of session_start(); and every time I was using a session variable, I was calling session_start. Precisely, I had session_start(); more than once on each page (without even calling session_destroy()). For example,

```
// 1st call
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['UserID']))    
{       
    // Do something    
}

else
{
   // Do something else
}

// .... some other code

// 2nd call
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['UserID']))    
{       
    // Do something totally different   
}

else
{
   // Do something else totally different
}
```

This was creating a performance issue for me. So I ended up calling `session_start();` just once at the very top of the page and everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call session_start once (and only once) in every file you want sessions to work in.

A common approach allowing you to only call it once is to have a dispatcher file as your index.php; call session_start in here and have this page include others based on the url's $_GET.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && file_exists('pages/'.$_GET['page'].'.php') {
        include $_GET['page'];
    }
?>
//www.mysite.com/index.php?page=fish will display /pages/fish.php with session access
```