# Wordpress Comet cache does not start after session_start() for first time?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, caching, comet-cache

I am using this code and after first entry of new user to page comet cache will not send cached content.

```
$status = session_status();
if($status == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    session_start();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['comparison']) && is_array($_SESSION['comparison']) && count($_SESSION['comparison'])>0){
            define('DONOTCACHEPAGE', TRUE);
    }
```

Comment: I think you might need to refine your question to get good answers. Off topic: you do not need to check for session status before calling `session_start()`

Comment: oh ... that might be the problem ... I think you always need to call `session_start()`. See that [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779744/php-session-start-function-why-i-need-it-everytime-i-use-anything-related-to)

Comment: Yes, but I must to check if session is NOT start

Comment: why? [PHP doc](http://at1.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php): "session_start() creates a session or **RESUMES the current one** based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie."

Comment: Comet cache working like  I am logged but I am not logged in. When I reload page comet cache works perfectly.