# When and where should I use session_start?

Tags: php, session

Exactly when and where should I use `session_start()` in PHP?

For example, say I have a login script that sets a session variable to tell whether or not the user is logged in. Must I then put the `session_start()` at the top of the script, or only right before I actually set the session variable if the login was successful?

```
<?php
// session_start(); here?

if (login($username, $password)) {
    // session_start(); or here?

    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
}
?>
```

Another case is this, according to w3schools

> **Note:** The session_start() function must be the very first thing in your document. Before any HTML tags.

Comment: As for your question you can start session wherever you want, but beware that session __must be__ started before any output. So it is considered a reasonable approach to start session at the top of a page.

Comment: And you should start your session before you use any session variables.

Comment: You can also only call `session_start()` once. Calling it multiple times will produce an error.

Comment: @u_mulder I added an additional thought

Comment: I use it first because I store the user's/visitor's IP and agent in it.

Comment: @super w3schools is infamous for providing faulty information. There is no reason that it must be the very first thing in your document. The only important thing is that it appears before any page content has been sent, whether that be HTML or anything else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have said, the absolute requirements of what you *must* do are:

- You must run `session_start` before you read or write to `$_SESSION` (otherwise it will just be an ordinary array and not saved anywhere).
- You must not run `session_start` twice during a single script execution (page load) unless you use `session_write_close` to close it in between.

There is an extra rule that technically has exceptions, but is best treated as absolute:

- Do not start the session after you have written any output (`echo`, HTML outside PHP blocks, etc), because PHP may not be able to send cookies to the browser if the server has already started sending the content.

There are two reasons you might want to *avoid* starting the session:

- PHP locks the session when you open it to avoid two processes writing conflicting data into it, so if you have several requests happening at once, you want to avoid them waiting for each other unless they really need to. For instance, if you're responding to an AJAX request, and don't need any data from the session, don't open it.
- As mentioned by symcbean, there is some cost to creating a new session, so if your site is busy with either legitimate or malicious traffic, you might want to serve some landing pages or error messages without starting it at all.

After that, it becomes a matter of style and architecture, but the rule of thumb that covers most of the above is "as soon as possible, if you're sure the page needs it".

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have output buffering enabled, the session_start() **must** come before anything other than headers are sent to the browser (as it sets a cookie in the header).

It **must** come before you attempt to reference the $_SESSION data.

In your example there are no html tags being output before either instance - so both would work.

There some cost to opening a session, so if you are doing additional, non-session based validation of the request, then deferring `session_start()` till these checks have passed does give you a bit more resillience against DOS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Starting the session at the top of the page is most of the times the best. But if you don't need the session for the whole document/code, you could always put it, as in this example, after the if() clause.

Comment: Edited the question with an additional thought

Answer (score 0):

The session_start() function can go anywhere in your code. You should just place it at the beginning of your document for consistency and call it a day. If you have a separate database or config file you are including on all your login/database driven pages, you should place it in there so you don't have to recode it into every page.